# POSIX open() hangs on SMB share

Tags: c++, linux, posix, smb

I have a problem where I mount a Windows SMB share under linux with `mount.cifs` and write to files from my C++ program. This works fine, but as soon as network problems arise (i.e. Windows server disconnect), opening the file with POSIX `open()` will hang indefinitely. The same happens for the POSIX `close()` call if the share disconnects while the file is open. Using `std::ofstream` reveals a similar problem.

Is there

- another version of `open()` / `close()` which returns after a timeout?
- a way to release the open call from another thread without killing the one that tries to open?
- a way to test beforehand if the call will hang?

Comment: So do you need POSIX (portable) or Linux-only solution? There is a new `io_uring` syscall on Linux which can do open/close asynchronously. It won't interrupt anything, but at least it won't block. Not sure if this will be you though...

Comment: @StaceyGirl Thanks, but target platform is Raspbian on Kernel 4.14, so `io_uring` is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syscalls are interrupted when a signal arrives; `errno` will return EINTR.

You can use `alarm()` before the syscall to schedule SIGALRM after a time-out period.

You can also use `alarm()` to cancel a pending SIGARLM if the syscalls returns successfully before the time-out period expires.

Comment: I tried it. It does stop the bloking but also terminates my application. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe `setitimer()` or `timer_create()` can be used for sub-second time-outs.

Comment: Have you registered a signal handler? Some signals have the default action of terminating the program if not handled or ignored.

Comment: Ok this answers the question then! Thank you.

Comment: I want to add a caveat: Signals do interrupt, yes, but in some cases not immediately: The `open()` call is interrupted immediately, but `close()` took 189 seconds in my experiment. Such processes can not even be interrupted by SIGKILL immediately, see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5648/286328) and [uninterruptable sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_(system_call)#Uninterruptible_sleep)